# JAVA- package ArcadeCounter does not exist

Tags: java

Please help me with the code for Java provided.. 
Whenever I try to compile, it gives me an error stating: "package ArcadeCounter does not exist"..
What does it mean by that?
I've tried what it says on the other sites but they don't seem to work either.

```
    import ArcadeCounter.java;


    /*TokenDispenser has 4 methods:
    •   addTokens() – adds a given number of tokens to the dispenser
    •   getTokensSold() – returns the number of tokens sold
    •   getCash() – returns the amount collected so far
    •   dispense() – dispenses tokens, given the cash amount*/


    public class TokenDispenser
    {
        // Declare your attributes here
    private int tokens = 0;
        private int tokensSold = 0;
        private double cash = 0.0;

        public void addTokens( int num )
        {
            tokens += num;
        }

        public int getTokensSold()
        {
            return tokensSold;
        }

        public double getCash()
        {
            return cash;
        }

        public void dispense( double amt )
        {
        if (amt < 30.00)
            {
                System.out.println( "Sorry, not enough cash."+amt );
            }
            else
            {
                if (tokens < 15)
                {
                    System.out.println( "Not enough tokens" );
                }
                else
                {
                    cash += 30;
                    tokensSold += 15;
                    tokens -= 15;
                    if (amt > 30)
                    {
                        System.out.println( "Change: " + (amt-30) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that there's no directory on the class path (including inside any jar files on the class path) named `ArcadeCounter`. The way you've written your `import`, that's what the compiler is looking for. The argument to `import` is the name of a class, including its package name. The compiler thinks `ArcadeCounter` is the package, and `java` is the class name.

It seems likely you have a class named `ArcadeCounter` which is not placed in a package; in that case, the `import` statement is not only unnecessary but invalid, so remove it; if `ArcadeCounter.java` is in the current directory, the compiler will find it.

Despite what several commenters have said, it is *not* legal to say

```
import ArcadeCounter;
```

Check the [Java Language Specification:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5)

> It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

Comment: Hi Ernest, is it possible to have a statement like "import ArcadeCounter.java"?

Comment: No -- the argument to import is the name of a class, not the name of a file. And for many revisions of Java, now, it's been illegal to import a class from the default package.

Comment: thanks..
I worked by removing " import ArcadeCounter.java; "...
Even I was thinking that the ArcadeCounter was an external file but just to make sure I didn't remove it before..